# Error on Updating RefineryCMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinerycms, refinery

I am trying to update from refinery 1.0.9 to 2.0.9 on ruby 1.9.3. I am getting this error:

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "refinerycms-core":
>
> ```
>  In Gemfile:
>    refinerycms-news (~> 1.2) ruby depends on
>      refinerycms-core (~> 1.0.0) ruby
>
>    refinerycms (~> 2.0.9) ruby depends on
>      refinerycms-core (2.0.9)
> ```

Can you help me understand the error and what to do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundler attempts to make sure that all of the dependencies of all gems (other gems, that is) are installed and meet version requirements specified by the gem designers.

In your Gemfile, you can specify versions of Gems in several ways, the `~>` method says the version can be greater than or equal to the number specified, but not so great that a major release can get installed without you knowing.

So it looks like you'll need to relax the restriction on version on the `refinery-news` gem which likely has a later version available than the `1.2` currently allowed (That version depends on refinerycms-core 1.0.0, but refinerycms needs a later version of the same gem).